# Error while navigating from extended splash screen in WP8.1RT

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, splash-screen

I used [this method (from msdn)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868191.aspx)  to extend splashscreen in my app but while navigating after showing extended splash screen it is throwing error.

Error:
The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

Code:

```
    void DismissedEventHandler(SplashScreen sender, object e)
    {
        dismissed = true;
        /*

          Here I will load data from web 

        */
        //Here i am unable to navigate on MainPage
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), LoadedData); 
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

    }
```

If you need more code then its same as of above mention link.

So how can navigate to MainPage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dispatch the navigation to run on the UI thread with Dispatcher.RunAsync https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx

Comment: Still can't navigate to main page

Comment: Now its working. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/451c3bce-c1bc-4bcc-be7d-d4b505cc1cf0/error-while-navigating-from-extended-splash-screen-in-wp81rt?forum=wpdevelop